# how to batch send eth or erc20 from multiple address to one address?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

How to batch send eth or erc20  from  multiple address to one address?

How to do it with code?

For example, I have 30 eth address.

I want to from 30 eth address  Transferring to  the one account in the contract.

how do I send  same amount ether/erc20 or different amount ether/erc20   in each account.

Comment: can you be more specific? do you want to send the content from 30 addresses to a single receiver contract? or do you want to send out an equal amount to a batch of addresses?

Comment: it seems that you haven't tried using https://multisender.app that does exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can write a contract with function like this

```
function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] dests, uint256[] values)
onlyOwner
returns (uint256) {
    uint256 i = 0;
    while (i < dests.length) {
       ERC20(_tokenAddr).transfer(dests[i], values[i]);
       i += 1;
    }
    return(i);
}
```

Or  use this tool: https://etherchain.tools/airdropper
, send ether/erc20 token to multiple addresses at once.

Transaction example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xca7c51cd32fd050b5ff6c0a9b39350d16251ec05e36d7fd438d4a19b3c004562